# Angular: Test Completes Before Observable Finalizes

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, angular-test

I trying to test an `interceptor` that adds a `finalize` operator to the pipeline and i'm unable to keep the test running long enough for the returned observable to, y'know, finalize.

Here's the `observable` returned from the `intercept` function:

```
return next.handle(request).pipe(
    finalize(() => {
      console.log('int finalize');
      this.activeRequests--;
      if (this.activeRequests === 0 ) {
        this.loader.endLoading();
      }
    }));
```

I'm trying to test that the return object calls `endLoading`

```
beforeEach(() => spyOn(svc, 'endLoading').and.callThrough());

fit('calls endLoading', async(() => {
  const expected = [];
  client.get('/someUrl')
    .pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        console.log('spec finalize');
        expect(svc.endLoading).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      })
    ).subscribe(response => expect(response).toEqual(expected));

  http.expectOne('/someUrl').flush(expected);
  expect(svc.endLoading).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
}));
```

When the test executes, the console outputs `spec finalize` before `int finalize` regardless of whether i use `async`, `fakeAsync` or `done`. I suspect loading the whole setup into a component stub and chaining `whenStable` calls would work, but it seems like there should be a better way. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should use `fakeAsync()` instead of `async()`. You can then flush the microtasks waiting using `flush()` or `tick(10000)`.

Comment: You should also use the mocking module for HttpClient. https://medium.com/netscape/testing-with-the-angular-httpclient-api-648203820712

Comment: Could you show your solution using `done` etc.? Its possible you put it in the wrong place.